# How to convert a .py file to .exe file and run on any pc without installing the libraries used in py file?

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller, py2exe, auto-py-to-exe

I want to convert a ".py" file to ".exe" file and I have converted that using *"auto-py-to-exe"*
But the file is not working on the other PC, it shows the error like this

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'.

I used 'pygame' in the .py project and the other PC doesn't have 'pygame' installed.

I'd like to convert ".py" file to ".exe" file and I'd like to run on any PC independent of whether it has Python or the respective libraries installed or not. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: A binary that includes all required libraries is called a "fat binary". I don't know if anyone still uses those.

Comment: What command did you used to make ".exe" file? Are you using "pyinstaller"or "auto-py-to-exe"? In pyinstaller, had you tried `pyinstaller --onefile game.py`?

Comment: If you don't want to get answers in `pyinstaller` then remove it from tags in question!

Comment: I haved "auto-py-to-exe" ,"py2exe" and "pyinstaller" as well. This cmd is also not working for me. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Then ask specific questions about the individual problems you have using each of those tools, with a [MRE] letting others see the problems themselves and test their answers. A blanket "how do I do this?" question is too broad to be on topic. If this means you ask one question about a problem encountered with pyinstaller, a second question about a different problem encountered with py2exe, etc., that's better than just one question that's too vague to be answerable.

Comment: BTW, the pygame docs themselves have a relevant section covering use with pyinstaller: https://pygame-gui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/freezing.html; make sure your question reflects the steps you took in trying to understand and follow that documentation.

Comment: These sorts of problems happen when people mix up python installations on their own computer. What’s happened is that the python installation with pygame is not the same installation as the one with PyInstaller. So when PyInstaller runs, it can’t find a pygame to package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You **@Starbuck5**

> ### As [@Starbuck5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13816541/starbuck5) mentioned in the comment.
>
> These sorts of problems happen when people mix up python installations on their own computer. What’s happened is that the python installation with pygame is not the same installation as the one with PyInstaller. So when PyInstaller runs, it can’t find a pygame to package. –
> Starbuck5

I have created a new virtual environment and installed libraries needed for my project and auto-py-to-exe in that virtual env. Then by using auto-py-to-exe, I converted my python file to .exe file and now it's working properly.

You can use any of these methods "auto-py-to-exe", "py2exe" or "pyinstaller", or any other method possible.
Just the libraries should be accessible by pyinstaller or another method you use.

The best way is to do this in a virtual environment.